# Parse cloud code on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

from what I understood Cloud Code is like a server, we can declare functions (only javascript?) to make app running lighter. Should I put every query on Cloud Code instead of iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put *every* query on Cloud Code but you can use it to host functions that should rest in a sever or you would like to change without requiring a app update.

As a quick example, you can create a function in cloud code to send a mail to a user friend, calculate some number with a variable that you don't know and want to change from time to time, or make some safety check with other servers before a payment.